# Patter design and Map function in Javascript. What dosen't work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, map-function

What is the difference between the fisrt code and the second? The fisrt work, but the second does not work, this return a array with number 4 and not a array object with corners = 4. The problem is in the map function.

Fist code

```
   const Strategy = {
            map : function(array){
                    const newArray = array.map((e) => { e.setCorners(4);  return e });
                    return newArray
                },
        }


    const objectCorners = function(corners){
    
        _corners = corners
    
    
    
        return ({
            corners : _corners
            getCorners : (() => { return corners}),
            setCorners : ((corners) => {_corners = corners}),
        })
    }
const array = [new objectCorners(3),new objectCorners(6),new objectCorners(7)]
const result = Strategy["map"](array)
console.log(result) // [{corners : 4},{corners : 4},{corners : 4}]
```

Second Code

```
 const Strategy = {
            map : function(array){
                    const newArray = array.map((e) => {return e.setCorners(4); });
                    return newArray
                },
        }


    const objectCorners = function(corners){
    
        _corners = corners
    
    
    
        return ({
            corners : _corners
            getCorners : (() => { return corners}),
            setCorners : ((corners) => {_corners = corners}),
        })
    }
const array = [new objectCorners(3),new objectCorners(6),new objectCorners(7)]
const result = Strategy["map"](array)
console.log(result) // [4,4,4]
```

Comment: Actually, neither of these seems to work, as the `_corners` variable is accidentally global.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. When executing the second snippet (after fixing the syntax error), I get `[undefined, undefined, undefined]` as expected, not `[4, 4, 4]`.

Comment: What does this have to do with functional programming?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between the fisrt code and the second? ... The problem is in the map function.

well, the difference is the map function ;-)

Specifically the return values.

In the case `(e) => { e.setCorners(4);  return e }`, `e` is explicitly returned

However, in the case `(e) => {return e.setCorners(4); }` the return value of `e.setCorners(4)` is returned. According to its definition

```js
setCorners : ((corners) => {_corners = corners})
```

it is equivalent to

```js
setCorners: function(corners) {
   _corners = corner
   // no return value, i.e. this function returns undefined
}
```

so `undefined` is returned

Notes to OP:

- please try your code before, as it is has syntax errors
- please put actual outputs.

  - In the first code you have `objectCorner` with values 3,6,7, but in the comments are values 4
  - In the second code, your commented output is `[4,4,4]`, while actually it was `[undefined,undefined,undefined]`

Comment: `(corners) => {_corners = corners}` does *not* `return` anything?!

Comment: @Bergi yes, of course, it does not return anything, thanks for correction. I was mis-influenced by the OP. I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Building modules is a popular functional programming technique. And instead of mutating state using getters and setters, we simply construct a new object -

```js
// Shape.js

const empty =
  { corners: 0 }

const create = (corners = 0) =>
  ({ corners })

const setCorners = (t = empty, corners = 0) =>
  ({ ...t, corners })

export { empty, create, setCorners }
```

Let's use our `Shape` module in a sample program -

```js
// Main.js

import { create, setCorners } from './Shape'

const Strategy =
  { map: shapes => shapes.map(s => setCorners(s, 4))
  }

const arr =
  [ create(3), create(6), create(7) ]

const result =
  Strategy.map(arr)
  
console.log(result, arr)
// [ { corners: 4 }, { corners: 4 }, { corners: 4 } ]
// [ { corners: 3 }, { corners: 6 }, { corners: 7 } ]
```

NB, the input array `arr` is not modified to construct the `result`. Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser

```js
// Shape.js
const empty =
  { corners: 0 }

const create =
  (corners = 0) =>
  ({ corners })

const setCorners =
  (t = empty, corners = 0) =>
  ({ ...t, corners })
  
// ---
// Main.js
const Strategy =
  { map: arr => arr.map(v => setCorners(v, 4))
  }

const arr =
  [ create(3), create(6), create(7) ]

const result =
  Strategy.map(arr)
  
console.log(result, arr)
// [ { corners: 4 }, { corners: 4 }, { corners: 4 } ]
// [ { corners: 3 }, { corners: 6 }, { corners: 7 } ]
```

Comment: While this is much better code than the OP's, I don't think this answers their question.